# microformat : how to add this into my website?

Tags: seo, microformats

I have used some tools for **checking my SEO** and I got the result:

*"Your website does not take advantage of Microformats.
Microformat is a technical semantic markup that can be used to better structure the data submitted to search engines.
Thanks to Microformats, Google regularly improves its search results presentation."*

**Can someone explain me how I can use these microformats and will they improve SEO ?**

Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microformats won't improve your ranking in search engines, however, some microformats like hReview may appear in search results as "rich snippets". See [this Google blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/help-us-make-web-better-update-on-rich.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing, see http://microformats.org/wiki/

And yes, it helps (a little) on SEO, as you provide more meta information to be indexed, as well as shows the care about making this information accessible.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of microformats you can make use of. One I always try to adopt is vcard

```
            <address class="vcard">
                <span class="org">Business Name</span>,
                <span class="adr">Unit 1234</span>
                <span class="street-address">Your Street level Address</span>,
                <span class="locality">Somewhere</span>,
                <span class="postal-code">P03TC0D3</span>,
                <span class="country-name">UK</span>.
                <span class="tel">01234 567890</span>
            </address>
```

If you dont want to use the Address element (new in HTML5), then just change it to a DIV and style accordingly. Makes your personal details much more accessible for search engines etc.

Answer (score 1):

Microformats helps search engine and it remove site structure ambiguity, might be improve indexing but do not hurt directly and affect SEO (or might be too little). @user300675 Same thing asked me one of my [blog](http://www.bloggerbonus.com) visitor on [this post](http://www.bloggerbonus.com/hfeed-warning-at-least-one-field-must-be-set-for-hatomfeed-how-to-fix/).

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who has Wordpress websites you can implement Wordpress plugins easily. You can find a list of plugins on this website.

http://microformats.org/wiki/wordpress-plugins

Each link takes you to a Wordpress download page where you can find more detailed description how to install these plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Microformats are very useful if we use in our company address & also not harmful for seo. I have also use in our site [Rhaasoft](http://www.rhaasoft.com/)